# Sort object having key value pair based on values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have declared an object.

var obj = {
    "1": "google",
    "2": "yahoo",
    "3": "msn",
    "4": "stackoverflow",
    "5": "github",
    "6": "jsfiddle",
    "7": "amazon",
    "8": "ebay"
};

I need to sort based on values and then push it to a array and I need to display the array. 
I have sorted the object based on values and pushed into array. But on display of array, the values are sorted based on keys. 
I found out the reason why it is happening, i.e., because keys are digits, on pushing to array or object the values are defaultly sorted based on keys. I don't want to change the values present in keys. Please let me know it der are any alternate to overcome this?

Thanks in Advance,
Chandan

Comment: It's not clear what you mean? Alphabetical sorting? Also how are you adding to array?

Comment: Why are you using an Object, when you can use an array?

Comment: Ex: Input: {"10":"India", "12": "Australia","17":"China"}. Output: {"12": "Australia", "17":"China","10":"India"}        Array or object anything is fine. But the data should be sorted based on values

Comment: @Pogrindis : I need to sort an object or array based on values, but keys should be numbers.

Comment: please add a wanted array. the keys of the object can actually not be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, talking about sorting I would like to point out that you can actually sort only arrays in JS. I mean you can "sort" an object too, but in such case the order is not guaranteed when you traverse the object later.

On the other hand, while sorting an array it doesn't make sense to preserve keys because if you do so, the final order of the values will be based on keys, so the sorting by values becomes senseless.

I would change input's format and sort an array of objects - it will allow you to both preserve the keys (and other attributes, if needed) and establish an order based on values. So, lets say, your input is

```js
var arr = [{id: "10", country:"India"}, {id:"12", country:"Australia"}, {id:"17", country:"China"}];

for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var temp = arr[i]; 
  for(var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp['country'] < arr[j]['country']; j--) arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
  arr[j + 1] = temp;
}

// or just use the default JS function:
/*arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.country > b.country;
});
*/

console.log(arr);
```

And to illustrate what I said at the beginning: this will sort the object as you need but the final order will not be preserved:

```js
var obj = {"10":"India", "12": "Australia","17":"China"}, sorted = {}; // or []
var arr = []; // array of countries

// sorting countries
for(var key in obj) arr.push(obj[key]);
arr.sort();

// creating a data structure "sorted" in a "sorted" order
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(var key in obj) if(obj[key] == arr[i]) { 
      console.log(arr[i]);  // seems it kind of writes it in the right order - Aus, Chi, Ind...
      sorted[key] = arr[i]; }
}
console.log(sorted); // ...but outputs differently (I use Chrome)
```

Comment: I have the same issue, i am able to sort the object by key, but in the end output is not the same :( . here is simple sort using lodash `_(inputObject).toPairs().sortBy(0).fromPairs().value();`

Answer (score 1):

using this you convert to array

```
var arr =  $.map(obj, function(el) { return el });
```

than you just need to sort according to requirement

Comment: Don't know about performances on extremely large objects (order of 10k rows), but this helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr,key)=>(arr[key]=obj[key],arr),[]);
```

Simply create a sparse array?

Creates this:

```
[undefined, "google", "yahoo", "msn", "stackoverflow", "github", "jsfiddle", "amazon", "ebay"]
```

Or you simply make an array out of it, doing:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj,Array.prototype);
```